# How I can set two images inline in HTML?

Tags: html, image

I will do set two images in inline, in the header of my website. But how I can do it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBlZs.jpg
I tried this... but (obviously) doesn't work.

```
 <img src="../wp-content/themes/sadra/images/logo/3d-header.png" width="350"><img src="../wp-content/themes/sadra/images/home/prot3-sadra-JSI22D-1.png" width="325">
```

Comment: Images are inline by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this flexbox example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, but the result is this:

https://imgur.com/uJsixkr

Is there a way to place closer to the center of the page?

Comment: If you mean the gap between the images, yes, there is a way. Just remove the `padding: 5px` part.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
   .img{float:left;}
</style>
```

or

```
<style>
   .img{display:inline;}
</style>
```

And then apply the class:

```
<img src="../wp-content/themes/sadra/images/logo/3d-header.png" width="350" class="img"><img src="../wp-content/themes/sadra/images/home/prot3-sadra-JSI22D-1.png" width="325" class="img">
```

Comment: Aren't `img`s inline by default?

Comment: Kind of... default is more like `inline-block`, inspector shows `inline`, but img tag is treated differently by the browser. Anyway I assume that ops wp theme changes that, if not, there would be no question about it.